I want to run my automated trading script on the server, how to keep my private key safe
I'm a newbie and I don't know how to keep my private keys safe on a cloud server, I'm afraid of being stolen by someone else or impersonating a transaction

Google Cloud KMS supports signing with ed25519 keys.  You will need to create a key ring and then a software generated (Unfortunately no HSM support) asymmetric ed22519 sign key in their GUI or CLI. Keeping your server and google account secure will still remain an issue, so it is a bit just shifting the goal post.
This Github repo uses the Google Java client library, but they provide clients in many languages.
